# how change pin or password simple with python

Tags: python

I beginner learn Python,

I try the source

```
try_pin = 0 
while True:
id = int(input("Type your Pin: ")
if id == 1111:
  break
print(" try type you pin again: ")
try_pin += 1

if try_pin == 5:
   print("Error")
```

so I make choice menu, the one menu is "Change pin", how i make from this source? I see many example make source with getpass. that make me confused

Comment: what exactly do you mean? do you want to change that '1111' number?

Comment: yes, i want change the number '1111', through the options menu with while true

Answer (score 0):

I am a beginner my self. You could try something like this

```
if try_pin == 5:
    print("Error")

change_id = input('Do you want to change pin y/n: ? ')
if change_id == 'y':
    id = change_id
else:
    print('Sorry you dont have access')
```